# How to select range in Vodolazkyi/VACalendar swift?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am using `Vodolazkyi/VACalendar` for one of my project and it's working good for multiple selection.

My problem here is I want to show selection range between two dates in `different color(like orange)` and start date and end date in `different color(like red)` i.e If 2 dates get selected like `5-2-2019` and `10-2-2019` then date within this two date should get selected...

Does anyone have idea how to achieve it? I didn't getting any clue..

Here is the link of library [Vodolazkyi/VACalendar](https://github.com/Vodolazkyi/VACalendar)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `func`  of adding multiple dates in `VACalendar.swift` named

```
func selectDates(_ dates: [Date])
```

You can use that like below

```
        var date = startDate // first date 5-2-2019
        let endDate = myEndDate // last date 10-2-2019
        var selectedDates: [Date] = [Date]()

        while date <= endDate {
            date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
            selectedDates.append(date)
        }
```

and the call the `selectDates` func Like below:

```
myVACalender.selectDates(selectedDates)
```

For changing color of selected dates set the `VADayViewAppearanceDelegate` of `VACalendarView`:

```
calendarView.dayViewAppearanceDelegate = self
```

and implement

```
func backgroundColor(for state: VADayState) -> UIColor {
   if state == .selected {
       return mySelectedColor
   }else {
       return myDefaultColor
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to show dates between start date and end date in different color.

Comment: In your question there is nothing about colors

Comment: I have updated the answer please check-accept-upvote if helpful.